# Access cache response headers with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, caching, response-headers

I am trying to access the response header "date" from one of my cached elements.

As you can see in the picture, my request does not return the correct timestamp. Instead, it returns null, and I don't know why.

[image]

Here is the code I use:

```
var cachedFile = "https://www.washingtonpost.com/resizer/rgjyoeu2BaoUyNiojHCKLjN9udM=/1484x0/arc-anglerfish-washpost-prod-washpost.s3.amazonaws.com/public/EXKAUXTXXUI6TJ57ZCSDXBHOGE.jpg";
caches.open("dynamic-content").then(cache => {
  cache.match(cachedFile).then(response => {
    if(! response){
        console.log("not found");
    }else{
        var element = response.headers.get('date');
        console.log(element);
    }
  })
})
```

My goal is to delete old cached files. Without using workbox or any plugins. If someone knows a way, I'm happy to be enlightened ;)

Comment: Try `response.headers.get('Date')`. If it still not working, you can try `console.log(response.headers)` to see what is inside the header object.

Comment: 'Date' returns null as well, and response.headers returns an Object, showing me which options I have ("append", "delete", "get") -> but it does not show actual header content of the cached file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try (your request return empty headers)

```js
let cache={};

var url = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.washingtonpost.com/resizer/rgjyoeu2BaoUyNiojHCKLjN9udM=/1484x0/arc-anglerfish-washpost-prod-washpost.s3.amazonaws.com/public/EXKAUXTXXUI6TJ57ZCSDXBHOGE.jpg";

async function load(url) {
  let c = cache[url];
  if(c) {
    console.log('Cached headers',c.res.headers);
  } else {
    let res = await fetch(url);
    c = cache[url] = {
      res,
      pic: await res.blob(),
    }
  }
  image.src=""; 
  image.src = URL.createObjectURL(c.pic);
}

function start() {
  load(url);
  btn.innerText="Load from cache";
  
}
```

```html
<button id="btn" onclick="start()">Load</button><br>
<img id="image" height="150"/>
```